# Finding total users count in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to calculate monthly/weekly growth rate for my website in Google Analytics(GA). I can't calculate it using the existing metrics because google analytics currently does not show the count of all users till date for my website. The user metric in GA only shows active users within the selected date range but to calculate growth rate, I need to know total users till date irrespective of the selected date range. Does anyone know how to do that? For example:

```
Date range: last month

Total users(till date): 100

Total users(in selected date range): 50

Total New users: 10

Actual growth rate = Total new users / Total users(till date)  = 10/100 = 10%

GA growth rate = Total new users / Total users(in selected date range) = 10/50 = 20%
```

Thus in GA I can only calculate time specific growth rate because it doesn't provide count of Total users(till date). I have tried custom metrics and custom variables but both of them have the same limitation.

Comment: Can you correctly identify each of you users? 
If not. It's impossible!

Comment: let's say I do have a user IP for each user, how would you do it then?